# Google TV HTML5 Template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, google-tv

I am using Template 1 of the Google TV HTML5 Templates: 
https://code.google.com/p/gtv-resources/

Live example: http://gtv-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/templates/html-01/index.html

I am trying to update the "dataprovider.js" file with a different list of sources.

Here is the original, unmodified file for reference:
http://pastebin.com/L2U54DPZ

I want to be able to specify my own video list. I've simplified this down to just one category with two videos.
http://pastebin.com/XvcC01BY

The menu shows up on the left hand side, but the videos do not display at all. Screenshot: http://i49.tinypic.com/35a0tbp.jpg

Here is a live example using my updated dataprovider.js file: http://rrcustom.com/stackoverflow/gtv-html5

Any help provided is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately OGG videos are not supported (see https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats) - since you are trying to play big buck bunny I suggest using an MP4 H.264 version of the video (or trans-code it yourself).

Comment: I tried using the .mp4 version and it still will not display the videos. Does everything here look right? http://pastebin.com/nKC4uw5i

Comment: Line 42 and 49 -> you are referencing ogg files -> ogg format is not supported on Google TV

Comment: I simplified things until I can get them working. I can only get the category to display http://i49.tinypic.com/35a0tbp.jpg 

Even this version of the dataprovider.js file isn't working right. Can you take a look to see what I am doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/ZL8uj9wU

Comment: can you make sure there is not some other error on the page that's stopping the rest of the app from working. Open your app in chrome use the console - see if there are any errors or warnings - please post it here or provide me a live link I can check.

Comment: One other thing I forgot to ask - are you testing the site on an actual google tv or just your browser?

Comment: I am using a Google Chrome browser. There are NOT any errors in the console. 

Here is a live example using the updated dataprovider.js file: 
http://rrcustom.com/stackoverflow/gtv-html5/

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest moving the event_videos instantiation to before the data instantiation.

(i.e. move line 19 - 34 to line 9)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it did not work. See my code here: http://pastebin.com/akJmYAua -- same results, http://i49.tinypic.com/35a0tbp.jpg -- do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you hosted this online anywhere so people can have a look?

Comment: Yes. Here is a live example using my updated dataprovider.js file: http://rrcustom.com/stackoverflow/gtv-html5

Comment: rrcustom: make sure that your data source complies with this example given here:http://www.videws.com/gtv/videosources.php?debug=1.    I notice that in your list of videos, each has title, subtitle, thumb, description, and a list of video URLs (usually just 1), but your description is a list of strings instead of just plain string.  This might be the cause for parsing failure.  Let me know if it works once you make sure that your videos are formatted properly.